# Juniper SRX routing based on network

Tags: routing, juniper, srx

So, a Juniper SRX 220 in a shared use building.  Two networks, 192.168.30.0/24 (The shared use) and 192.168.31.0/24 (the private network).  We had once cable modem, and it currently allows only the 31.0 network across a VPN to corporate.  Now they put in a Point to Point Fiber, and we need to send all traffic on the 31.0 across the P2P, and all 30.0 across the Cable modem.
GE0/0 - Cable
GE0/1 - LAN
GE0/2 - Fiber P2P

Currently, the default route is to 0/0, and traffic for corporate across the VPN st.0

Since they now want all traffic on the 31.0 (including Internet bound traffic) to go across the VPN to the main office for tracking purposes, I will need to change the default route for the 31.0 network, while leaving the 30.0 network default route the 0/1 default gateway.

I have not been able to find anything to help me do this, thoughts on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called routing-instances, basically you need to maintain separate routing tables. This can be a bit heavy for a beginner, so you might have to play with it to get it right.

Here's a link: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23300&actp=search

And here's probably a better explanation.

http://aconaway.com/2012/10/31/junos-basics-routing-instances/

Comment: Also keep in mind, what you've described to me will send ALL traffic (including Internet bound traffic) across the tunnel. Be sure you're remote side is prepared to provide you Internet services :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to configure 2 default routes in this case, then that should solve your purpose.
You can make use of routing instances which in turns makes 2 routing tables to choose from .

The following KB also gives an idea for the same.
https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB23300&actp=search

Have a look, try it in your lab and let us know if you have questions.

Cheers 
Happy Configuring!